# How to restrict user language on login?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

We have a set of Windows 2003 Terminal servers with Windows MUI packs installed. The servers belong to a Windows AD domain TERDOMAIN. All the users who access the servers belong to the AD domain USRDOMAIN.

TERDOMAIN and USRDOMAIN belong to different forests, but there is a trusted relationship setup between the domains so that user can login to the terminal servers.

I want to make sure that when a user logs in to the terminal server, he can see the Windows desktop in his language of choice. How can this be achieved? Can this be done using group policies?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Group Policies. You can create one policy for each language group and enforce that particular language to the group. This way if your users want their environment in a specific  language, all you need to do is move them to the language group.

Here is the procedure you have to follow:

In "Active Directory Users and Computers", right click the Terminal Servers Organizational Unit (create this unit, if you don't habe this and insert all your TS Server Computers). and select "Properties." Create group policy objects for all your available language, let's say "TSAccountsEnglish" and "TSAccountsSpanish."

Select the policies and click *"Edit"*. Under *"User Configuration" > "Administrative Templates" > "Control Panel" > "Regional and Language Options"* there is *"Restrict selection of Windows menus and dialogs language."* Enable this option and choose the language for this object.